# printf seems to be ignoring string precision

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting

So, I'm a bit stymied.  According to `man 3 printf` on my system, the string format `"%5s"` should use the specified precision to limit the number of characters printed from the string argument given.

```
% man 3 printf
PRINTF(3)                BSD Library Functions Manual                PRINTF(3)

NAME
     printf, fprintf, sprintf, snprintf, asprintf, vprintf, vfprintf,
     vsprintf, vsnprintf, vasprintf -- formatted output conversion

...
     s       The char * argument is expected to be a pointer to an array of
             character type (pointer to a string).  Characters from the array
             are written up to (but not including) a terminating NUL charac-
             ter; if a precision is specified, no more than the number             
             specified are written.  If a precision is given, no null
             character need be present; if the precision is not specified, or
             is greater than the size of the array, the array must contain a
             terminating NUL character.
```

But my test code doesn't confirm this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char const * test = "one two three four";
        printf("test: %3s\n", test);
        printf("test: %3s\n", test+4);
        printf("test: %5s\n", test+8);
        printf("test: %4s\n", test+14);
        return 0;
}
```

It outputs

```
test: one two three four
test: two three four
test: three four
test: four
```

When I think I should be getting

```
test: one
test: two
test: three
test: four
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is the man page just lying to me?

FYI: I know I could (in general) hack the string, and insert temporary `'\0'` to terminate the string (except when it's a `char const *`, like here, I'd have to copy it instead), but it's a PITA (especially if I'm trying to print two halves of something in the same printf), and I want to know why the precision is being ignored.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're not setting the *precision*, you're setting the *field width*. The *precision* always starts with a `.` in the format specification.

```
printf("test: %.3s\n", test);
```

Comment: The first numeric parameter is _named_ the "field width" or sometimes just "width". It does, though, specify the minimum field width.