# Can anyone explain me the working of this C code?

Tags: c

I don't know how this code is working?

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
     char *s = "PRO coder";
     int n = 7;
     printf("%.*s", n, s);
     return 0;
 }
```

The result I am getting is "PRO cod"

Comment: Yep, it's definitely working as it ought to.  You might want to take a look at the manual pages for printf and format strings.  Specifically, how to specify the precision (or in this case, the number of characters/numbers to print).

Comment: This section has an amost identical example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Precision_field

Comment: Also look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478115/printf-seems-to-be-ignoring-string-precision

Comment: And the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776824/what-is-the-meaning-of-s-in-a-printf-format-string describes how to think about it really well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` format string `%.*s` takes two arguments, `*` for the number and finally `s` for a string, so it prints the first 7 characters of the string pointer `s`. In general, anytime there is a number, you may use `*` instead to read it as an argument.

`%7s` would print seven characters or more if the string were longer, while `%.7s` would print up to seven characters. So sometimes one would write `"%*.*s", 7, 7, s` to print exactly 7 characters.